# How do you create an archive file which unarchives into the current folder?

Tags: usb, zip, archive

At the moment, if I create a TAR or ZIP file `foo.tar` - containing multiple files and directories - when I double click on the archive it creates a folder `foo` containing all of the archived items.

Is there a way to have an archive extract itself - when opened from Finder - so that the files are at the same level as the archive was?

I'm trying to distribute an archive which users can use to setup a USB drive with a custom icon etc, however this requires copying hidden files into the USB drive's root, so I can't just get them to "copy/paste from this network directory"

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken (always a possibility), this behavior is set by the program extracting the archive file, not by the archive file itself.

Comment: Do you know of any archivers which do work in the way I'm hoping?

Comment: It wouldn't really matter, because it's up to the *unarchiver*. You would need to get people to install an unarchiver, and possibly set its preferences, before they extracted your archive. Which sounds like more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is:

1. Create your .zip file, `foo.zip` with the desired USB drive contents.
2. Create an applescript named `USB Drive Installer` or whatever:

   ```
   tell application "Finder" to get folder of (path to me) as Unicode text
   set myDir to POSIX path of result
   set DestinationDirectory to choose folder with prompt "Select USB Drive Destination"
   do shell script "/usr/bin/ditto -xk " & myDir & "/foo.zip" & quoted form of DestinationDirectory
   ```
3. Create another .zip with those two files. Provide instructions to run the applescript after the files are extracted.